# What are the configs to change after you decrypt a LUKS encrypted partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, arch-linux, luks, fstab

I just decrypted my root partition encrypted with LUKS2. But the fstab still shows the root with the /dev/mapper/secret entry with a different UUID than the partition. Do I have to generate the fstab again by using a live USB?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix LUKS UUID (from `cryptsetup luksDump`) with the filesystem UUID (from `blkid`).

For example:

```text
# df /home
Filesystem          1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cr_home 262011908 245859184  16152724  94% /home
# blkid /dev/sys/home
/dev/sys/home: UUID="8f3a0f07-fe26-4509-9b6e-a98a9589222a" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
# blkid /dev/mapper/cr_home
/dev/mapper/cr_home: LABEL="home" UUID="11097148-5911-42f6-b372-499d99cc167d" TYPE="xfs"
```